# Reports and Analytic for big data

Tags: reporting, data

I'm looking for an advise on how to handle large number of records in reports.
In my use case I might have million of records a month which I'll keep a 3 month history of.
These records are for user activity and should be available for reporting and analytic.
This activity records are associated with other records I manage like a Subscriber record...

Did anyone trey working with big data in SF?
What is the recommended approach?
Is it at all doable?

If not what is the suggested alternative? Database.com? Something else?

Comment: A couple of potentially useful resources: YouTube [Large Data Volumes on Force.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unhLL899Cjo), PDF: [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ldv/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, beside the SF resources, I'm looking into some real life experience and advise. Are there any performance issues with so mach data in reports? Is the cost of SF storage for so many records makes this alternative not cost effective.

Answer (score 2):

You can contact customer support to get the fields used for filters in your reports to be indexed (custom indexing), this could improve the reports performance.

However having said that i would recommend having an external system to store these hisotrical activities on periodic basis and run reports on it. Salesforce.com space can be extended but its not cheap moreover after some time maintaining the large data (archiving and deleting) in itself becomes a huge task and would incur additional IT overhead.