# Design Query for implementing high volume periodic imports

Tags: apex, data-loader, bulk-api

We plan to  implement periodic bulk import of  records into our Salesforce.

If implemented, then we would be importing around 2-2.5 Million Records into a custom object per day.

Since this is a significantly high volume we were wondering what sort of limits it will (if) impact .

Can someone help ?

Do let me know if you need any other info

Comment: You would use up the [data storage limit](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_storage_allocation.htm) pretty quickly.

Comment: Tx. Also I assume that we will be hitting API usage limits also. If we bulk import 25000000..That will be (25000000/200 = 12500 API calls)..This is 50% of the Daily API Usage limit..Am I right with this calculation ?

Comment: Is your data transactional ?Keep transactional data only inside SF

Comment: The data is a financial adjustment record (click level) of our customers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, data storage will be your main reason for concerns. API limits can be avoided using [Bulk API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_Left.htm#CSHID=asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fasynch_api_concepts_limits.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp). With it you can import up to 10K records in a single batch and although there is 5K limit on number of batches processed per rolling 24h, you should be fine for that limit(2.5m / 10k = 250). You might have to reduce batch size to fit into 10MB limit on batch size though.

Answer (score 2):

Consider keeping this data outside SFDC and integrate data presentation in force.com app. The volume of data you want to import on daily basis is huge. Please also read these threads: [1] [can salesforce handle 50 or 70 million records?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27462/can-salesforce-handle-50-or-70-million-records) [2] [Reports and Analytic for big data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10499/reports-and-analytic-for-big-data)